# can't use containsKey method in Array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, flutter, dart

I'm trying to check whether a user has entered their correct login details. If the user has entered the right details they get a status of 1 returned. I'm trying to use the containsKey method to see whether the key is 1 button it returns an error. Please help me.

```
var rsp = await loginUser(user, pass);

                            print(rsp);
                            
                            if (rsp.containsKey('status')) {
                              if (rsp['status'] == 1) {
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => Home()));
                              }
```

It prints this: So I know it works and returns an array

```
flutter: {"status":1,"status_text":"Success","user_arr":{"firstname":"Murat ","lastname":"obrien","email":"murray18@gmail.com","username":"hello","password":"hello"}}
```

I get this error:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance method 'containsKey'.
Receiver: "{\"status\":1,\"status_text\":\"Success\",\"user_arr\":{\"firstname\":\"Murat \",\"lastname\":\"obrien\",\"email\":\"murray18@gmail.com\",\"username\":\"hello\",\"password\":\"hello\"}}"
Tried calling: containsKey("status")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your response is returning an encoded string version of a json array. Try the following to transform `rsp` into an array (known as a [`Map`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/Map-class.html) in dart):

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

var rsp = await loginUser(user, pass);
res = jsonDecode(rsp);

if (rsp.containsKey('status')) {
  if (rsp['status'] == 1) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked for the containsKey, but how do I now check that that key 'status' is == 1? Thank you!

Comment: No problem and thanks! I think your existing code should now work as `rsp` will be a `Map` so you should be able to access the value that's contained at `res['status']`. Maybe `rsp['status']` is returning a string version of `1` rather than an int? In this situation I would do `print(rsp['status'] == 1)` just inside the first if statement so you can see what's getting output, then based on that result tweak the code until you arrive at the right condition.

Comment: Something you can also do to ensure that `rsp` is the type you need is to use `Map<String, dynamic>.from(jsonDecode(rsp))` this allows dart to know that you're working with a Map with string values and so any syntax errors will get flagged when working with `rsp`.

Comment: Thank you very much, printing (rsp['status'] == 1) returned a boolean of true, and so I checked if true.